# Plotly JavaScript (JS) : Define a gridlines with step (X/Y) in chart

Tags: javascript, grid, axes, plotly.js

I'm posting this topic because I wanted to know if it was possible to define a gridlines within a graph.

The code is quite simple :

```
        var data = [];
        var layout = {
            xaxis: {
                range: [0, 5],
                ticks: 'outside',
                dtick: 0.1,
                gridcolor: 'rgb(152,152,152)',
            }, 
            yaxis: {
                range: [0, 25], 
                ticks: 'outside', 
                dtick: 1,
                gridcolor: 'rgb(152,152,152)',
            },
        };
        Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

This code displays the following example :

[image]

Nevertheless what I would like to display is :

[image]

The gridlines is kept in the chart but not all tick values are displayed

I haven't found a solution to display gridlines without using ticks but maybe there are other solutions.

Thanks for your help

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to set *tickvals* with empty *ticktext*:

```
        tickvals = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],
        ticktext = ['0.1','','0.3','','0.5']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).